# How to return a user to the previous position on a page he was before clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a website. I have implemented a load on scroll function. Now the issue is that when a user clicks on a link and then presses the back button, he is not returned back to the position on the page where he clicked, instead he is redirected to the top of the page. How can I implement such requirement in PHP, so that the user is redirected back to the same location similar to Instagram?

I know that cache needs to be stored and then retrieved, but don't know how to do it or is there any other approach also?

Here is the code for the load on scroll:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


 var limit = 6;
 var start = 0;
 var action = 'inactive';



 function load_data(limit, start)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetcher.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{limit:limit, start:start},
   cache:false,
   success:function(data)
   {
      //console.log(data+"sjdfksdcsjcbljd");

    $('#load_data').append(data);

    if(data.length < 5)
    {

     $('#load_data_message').html('<img src="img/spinner.gif" height=200 width=200 align="middle" style="visibility: hidden;">');
     action = 'active';
    }
    else
    {
     //$('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>Please Wait....</button>");

     $('#load_data_message').html('<img src="img/spinner.gif" height=200 width=200 align="middle">');
     action = "inactive";
    }
   }
  });
 }

 if(action == 'inactive')
 {
  action = 'active';
  console.log("onload");
  load_data(limit, start);
 }
 $(window).scroll(function(){

  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
  {

   action = 'active';
   start = start + limit;
   console.log("Scrolled"+start);
   setTimeout(function(){
    load_data(limit, start);
    $("#all").trigger('click');  
   }, 1000);
  }
 });


 setTimeout(() => {
  $("#all").trigger('click');  
 }, 1000);;

});
</script>
```

and here is fether.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/connect.inc.php';
if(isset($_POST["limit"], $_POST["start"]))
{
 $today = date("Y-m-d");
 $query = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY event_date DESC LIMIT ".$_POST["start"].", ".$_POST["limit"]."";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $event_date =  $row['event_date'];
    if(strtotime($today) <= strtotime($event_date)) {
      // Event has not yet finished
      echo "<div class=\"col-lg-4 col-md-6 pt-4 mycard upcoming\">";
    } else {
      // Event has finished
      echo "<div class=\"col-lg-4 col-md-6 pt-4 mycard past\">";
    }
        echo "<a class=\"card-link\" href=\"eventdetails.php?id=" . $row['event_id'] . "\">
              <div class=\"card px-2 pt-2\">
                <img class=\"card-img-top img-fluid\" src='images/".$row['event_bannername']."'>
                <h4 class=\"card-title text-center mt-2\">" . $row['event_title'] . "</h4>
              </div></a>
            </div>";
    }
 }


?>
```

http://ieee.shahandanchor.com
http://ieee.shahandanchor.com/events.php

This is the link to the website I am trying to implement it. The load on scroll might not be live yet on this link but I have it on my localhost

Comment: Not sure of an exact solution; however, I'd say find a way to catch the scroll position before the user exits the page and store it globally somehow using a cookie, global variable, database column, readable file, etc.. My choice would be to use a cookie.

You can get the scroll position of an element using <element>.scrollX and <element>.scrollY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: infinite scroll and the back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181903/jquery-infinite-scroll-and-the-back-button)